# What would be a good research question on Nationalism?

Tags: research-process, thesis, politics, china, asia

I'm trying to find a research question on Nationalism in Taiwan, Hong Kong and PRC. I need a research question that can be supported with data readily available online. If anyone can help me that would be great! I'm also open to other suggestions. Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Typically you would begin some research into a subject like this by asking about past or present social and cultural issues in the region, rather than by asking about a research question per se.

China is a diverse country. “Chinese” refers to not one single spoken language, but a family of many languages. Similarly, the ethnic makeup of China is more complicated than many realize. Although 90% citizens of the PRC beong to the so-called “Han” ethnicity, some 10% of the population (100+ million people, so not insignificant) may identify with a different ethnic group.

Some of the prominent current-day issues in this area include relations between the PRC and Tibet, Taiwan’s unrecognized status, the “one country, two systems” policy as implemented in Hong Kong, etc. Historically it may be interesting to investigate the Sino-Japanese relations through history or possibly the origin of Korea, which has a lot to do with China.